# Angular2 - Redirect after submit does not show updated data

Tags: angular

I have the following component which has two input fields and a submit. 
Upon submit the data is sent to the server and the page is redirected to the task page.

But the data in this page is not updated as the task page has to get the data from the DB.

if I refresh the page , or navigate out and back in.. the updated data is visible.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'edit-tasks',
    template: `<div mdl class="mdl-grid demo-content">

          <div class="demo-graphs mdl-shadow--2dp mdl-color--white mdl-cell mdl-cell--8-col">
                <h3>EDIT Task Page</h3>   

                <form action="#" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
                  <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
                    <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="taskname" [(ngModel)]="data.taskname"/>
                    <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="taskname">Task Name</label>

                   </div> <br/>
                  <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield">
                    <textarea class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" rows= "5" id="taskdesc" [(ngModel)]="data.taskdesc"></textarea>
                    <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="taskdesc">Task Description</label>
                  </div> <br/>

                <br/>  <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-button--colored" type="submit">SAVE</button>
                </form>

         </div>

    `,
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, MDL]

})

export class EditTaskComponent {

    data: any;

    constructor(private apartmentService: ApartmentService,private router: Router, private sharedService: SharedService) {
      this.data=this.sharedService.temp;
      console.log(JSON.stringify(this.data));
    }

    onSubmit(form) {    
    this.apartmentService.updateTask(this.data);
    this.router.navigate(['Tasks']);    
    }
}
```

**Update  as per @Günter Zöchbauer's suggestion**

```
    onSubmit(form) {    
    this.apartmentService.updateTask(this.data).then(_=>this.router.navigate(['Tasks']));   <-- changed this as per @Günter Zöchbauer suggestion and it works :)
    this.router.navigate(['Tasks']);    
    }
```

In the service.ts

```
updateTask(data:any){

    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=> {
      this.http.put(`./api/newtask/${data._id}`,
      JSON.stringify(data),{ headers: new Headers({'Content-Type':'application/json'})
    })
    .map((res: Response) => res.json()).subscribe(data => {resolve(data)}, error => reject(error))
  });   
}
```

How can I handle this through observable ? Can I avoid Promise altogether ?

Comment: Can't you redirect only after the `updateTask()` is complete?

Comment: `updateTask()` is complete when I redirect. it's the target page that has to make a `GET` call from DB to show the updated data.

Comment: That sounds unlikely. If `updateTask()` does a call to the server then you need to chain it somehow with `this.router.navigate()` like `...updateTask(this.data).then(_ => this.router.navigate(['Tasks']));` otherwise `this.router.navigate()` will be executed before the call to the server even started.

Comment: You can return an observable from `updateTask(this.data)` and then use `subscribe()` instead of then. Did the change fix your update issue?

Comment: Yes. It fixed it. Thank you very much.