# Refresh component after doing a router.navigate

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, ag-grid

I am trying to navigate from one component to another component using :

```
this.router.navigate(['/path/'], '_blank');
```

The problem is that the component I am navigating to, is already created and its ngOnInit method is not executed when I navigate back to the page. I am trying to refresh the data showing on the page. This is in the ngOnInit function of the target component:

```
this.sub = this._DataService.getData().subscribe(data=> {
        this.data= data;
    });
```

How can I tell the target component, that the data on the page is always refreshed when doing a navigation?

I am using Ag-Grid to show the data in a table. In the NgOnInit function:

```
this.gridOptions.rowData = this.data;
```

The component I am originally coming from, is a form to add a new object. After submitting that object, it should redirect to the grid and show the new object. That is why the Grid should be updating its data, but because of some reason, it only does that when I manually refresh it through a context menu action in the grid, not on navigation.

The submit function in the form looks as the following:

```
 onSubmit(data) {
    this._DataService.addData(data.value).subscribe();
    this.router.navigate(['/data/']);
}
```

Comment: What is `'_blank'`?

Comment: Nothing, it was still there because I have been messing with it.

Answer (score 9):

If you navigate to the same route and only parameter values change, move the initialization code out from `constructor` and call it from `constructor` and when route params change:

```ts
constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute) {
  route.params.subscribe(val => this.initialize())
}
```

Comment: Hard for me to tell because I can't know what's going on on your system. Your question doesn't contain much code.

Comment: That is because there is really not a lot to it. I am using Ag-Grid to show data in a table. I'll add some more information to my original question

Comment: I doubt the component you're navigating to is already created. If you navigate away it will be destroyed, if you navigate back it will be recreated. Only if you stay at the same route and navigate so that only route parameters change, the component will be kept alive. But it's hard to say because your question doesn't contain any information about that.

Comment: I can confirm that this method works and "refreshes" the component. Shouldn't be downvoted because it does what the question asks. I've tried this solution and managed to renavigate to the component, but I somehow can only add data, not start with a clean sheet (not a question but a heads up)

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it by changing my onSubmit function to:

```
  onSubmit(data) {
    this._DataService.addData(data.value).subscribe(data => {
        this.router.navigate(['/path]);
    });
}
```

Thanks to this question: [Angular2 - Redirect after submit does not show updated data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37563145/angular2-redirect-after-submit-does-not-show-updated-data)

Answer (score 0):

i implemented an redirect component

this.router.navigate(['/redirect/', window.location.pathname]);

Comment: Redirect components are sometimes good for a sure-fire re-initialization.